# Port forward with OpenVPN Tunnel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

I'm trying to hide my webserver by using an openvpn tunnel site-to-site to another server.

This is the schema:

```
SERVER1                        SERVER2
WEBSERVER               <=>    (OPENVPN CLIENT)        <=>  PEOPLE
(OPENVPN SERVER)               Private IP: 10.8.0.2
Private IP: 10.8.0.1
```

Of course, both SERVER1 and SERVER2 have also a public ip (connected to the WAN), private ip stands for the ip used to link them with the vpn.

I want people to access the webserver on the SERVER1 via SERVER2 in order to hide the SERVER1 public IP.

I created a site-to-site tunnel with openvpn, so from the SERVER2 I can access the webserver on the SERVER1 by using the openvpn private ip, however I can't access it from the SERVER2 public IP.

Thanks in advance for your help!

ip a output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:63:f1:37:d8:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet PUBLIC_IP/20 brd PUBLIC_IP
 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.19.0.5/16 brd 10.19.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a03:b0c0:3:e0::c4:6001/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9863:f1ff:fe37:d8f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
40: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.2 peer 10.8.0.1/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a proxy web server on your Server2. The OpenVPN client has a non-public IP address, I suppose?  At least it's not routed to Server2 from People.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip a` on the Server2. Also, please test whether you can access the webserver from Server2 (commandline, e.g. `wget http://123.45.67.89/` where you enter the OpenVPN client IP address visible on Server2).

Comment: @Ned64 ip a output added on the question.

Comment: OK, now let's try `wget http://10.8.0.2/` on the Server2!  Does it save a file?

Comment: If i do `wget http://10.8.0.2/`, it doesn't save anything because that ip is the local ip of the SERVER2, however if I do `wget http://10.8.0.1/` it works, it downloads index.html

Comment: Oops, yes, that's what I meant :-)

Comment: Yes, it works, it downloads index.html @Ned64

Comment: OK, I tried a reply, please let me know how well it works and we'll iterate as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the traffic incoming into your Server2 (on port 80 and/or 443) to your Server1's OpenVPN tun IP address.

There are more than one way to do this. I personally have done the following in the past:

**Option 1:**
Run a web server on Server2 and forward all requests to the "local" IP address 10.8.0.1 for those two ports.  The web server may even cache requests, which I found advantageous.

**Option 2:**
Using IP forwarding (less overhead).  On Server2:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then forward (*):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d PUBLIC_IP --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:80
```

You may need masquerading, too:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

If it works save the first option to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

and save your IP tables rules. This depends on your distribution!  In CentOS 7:

```
mv -i /etc/sysconfig/iptables /etc/sysconfig/iptables.bak
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl mask firewalld
yum install iptables-services 
systemctl enable iptables
```

You mileage may vary since there have been many changes to firewalls and variations between distributions in the last few years.

(*)
In case you need more than just that one port you can use a range:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d PUBLIC_IP --dport 80:1080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:80-1080
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ned64, option 2 is working!! If can I ask you another question, is possibile to move the whole traffic from the 10.8.0.1 (from all the ports) to the public ip in SERVER2?

Comment: @Lorenzo You may not want all ports, especially not for the ports 22, openVPN ports etc. I will add a range option above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for tour help @Ned64!

Comment: You are welcome, @Lorenzo! Have you upvoted the question, as it solves the problem? It looks like it has 0 upvotes. Thanks.

Comment: Of course @Ned64, but stackexchange tell me "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.", I've also marked it as solution of my problem

Comment: @Lorenzo Thanks - didn't know :-)

Comment: now it worked, upvoted! @Ned64